# Reading the values from a custom yml file which hold resilience4j configration

Tags: java, circuit-breaker, resilience4j

I have a custom yml file configuration that holds the configs needed for the circuit breaker implemented in resilience4j.

```
resilience4j:
circuitbreaker:
instances:
serviceA:
eventConsumerBufferSize: 3
failureRateThreshold: 50
minimumNumberOfCalls: 2
automaticTransitionFromOpenToHalfOpenEnabled: true
waitDurationInOpenState: 5s
permittedNumberOfCallsInHalfOpenState: 3
slidingWindowSize: 10
slidingWindowType: TIME_BASED
```

The method that invokes the custom config file mentioned above:

```
@Override
@CircuitBreaker(name = "serviceA", fallbackMethod = "ContactsServiceDown")
public void runCommands(String val) {
    //code logic
}
public void ContactsServiceDown() {

    System.out.println("service down");
}
```

I have created a test method that calls `runCommands` and throws an exception whenever it is invoked which executes more than 25 times, but I am not getting a hit in the fallback method. Is there any possible way we can read the values from resilance4J.yml file?

Comment: Please follow [ask], not forgetting about grammar, too

Comment: It doesn't seem the yml file is well indented. Moreover, where exactly is the exception launched in your test?

Comment: The fallback method should accept an argument of type Exception. Your fallback method signature should be updated as `public void ContactsServiceDown(String val, Exception e)`